# How to fix InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type for Register

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I got error while I was preparing register `Index` page. I didn't open cause which give error like this:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[HotelProject.EntityLayer.Concrete.AppUser]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'HotelProject.WebUI.Controllers.RegisterController'.

[Thats Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhRUO.png)

```
//RegisterController
using HotelProject.EntityLayer.Concrete;
using HotelProject.WebUI.Dtos.RegisterDto;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HotelProject.WebUI.Controllers
{
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
    public RegisterController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(CreateNewUserDto createNewUserDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }
        var appUser = new AppUser()
        {
            Name = createNewUserDto.Name,
            Email = createNewUserDto.Mail,
            Surname = createNewUserDto.Surname,
            UserName = createNewUserDto.Username,
            //WorkLocationID = 1
        };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, createNewUserDto.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
        return View();
        }
    }
}

//Program CS
using HotelProject.DataAccessLayer.Concrete;
using HotelProject.EntityLayer.Concrete;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Reflection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

 builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
 builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());



 var app = builder.Build();

 // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
 if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
 app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
 app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseRouting();

 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();

 app.MapControllerRoute(
  name: "default",
  pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

 app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

But you haven't register any asp.net identity service yet, So you cannot use usermanganer. You should have codes like below to use asp.net identity. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: ApplicationDbContext and AddDefaultIdentity redline.I post image include error above

Comment: @Berkay, ApplicatinDbContext is the databse stores your userinforamtion. You should have something similar if you are using usermanager. I suggest you check this doc about asp.net core built-in identity https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-setup/.